# Is there any way to see when a youtube livestream started?

Tags: streaming, youtube, video-streaming

I was wondering if anyone knows a way to find out when a YouTube livestream started. I've tried googling around but can't seem to find a solution. Of course I can see the date of the stream, but I'm trying to figure out a way to see when it began exactly. I am not the content owner. Thanks!

Comment: Note: [this question was previously asked here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/141495/is-there-a-way-to-find-the-time-a-youtube-livestream-started), but was closed as off-topic. Per a commenter's recommendation, it looks like the author then asked on Super User, but that question was then migrated here.